# A screen on boot on my Windows 10 system warns that BitDefender threat scanner is compromised. But I dont have that program on my system

Tags: windows

On boot, windows displays a warning that BitDefender Threat scanner has a problem and I should report it to the company. Which I have done, no reply. But every single file of BitDefender has been eliminated from this machine, although it didnt want to go......  Win 10, right up to date.

Comment: "although it didnt want to go" .. & obviously still hasn't gone. Usual trick would be to reinstall then seek assistance from BD for *correct* uninstallation.

Comment: Some viruses uninstall or disable the antivirus when they establish themselves. If your computer is infected, see [link](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit).

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason you see this error is due to the Spybot’s corrupted file. One of its DLL gets damaged, and you start seeing the BitDefender Threat Scanner error. You can download Bitdefender Removal Tool to remove the Bitdefender correctly.

For more details, please refer to the following article:

[A problem has occurred in BitDefender Threat Scanner [Solved]](https://www.worthwagon.com/bitdefender-threat-scanner-problem/)